# Memory leak in NSString stringWithUTF8String

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I am making a call to a database. After my call, I've found leaks in NSString. Anybody have a solution to remove it?

```
 NSString *pic = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 5)];
```

In above code, I found 90% leaks. I just read data from database.

Comment: Have you run the Analyzer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please explain the question well else others can't identify your exact problem.

I think you are you are assigning the value of **[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 5)];** to your class object property.

You can release the assigned class string property in the corresponding class **dealloc** method.Also set it nil.

**Example:**

if you are doing

```
YourClass *classObj =[ YourClass  alloc] init];

classObj.myStringvariable = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 5)];
```

the class structure will like

```
@interface YourClass {

    NSString *myStringvariable ;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain)  NSString *myStringvariable ;
```

**.m file** will be

```
@synthesise myStringvariable ;


-(void)init{

 myStringvariable  = @"";

}

-(void)dealloc{

 [myStringvariable  release];
 myStringvariable  = nil;
}
```

Check it.. this structure will not show memory leak.

Comment: I have done the same thing and found no leak but thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling `sqlite3_finalize()` to free up memory?

If you are doing it, then the leak is possibly with the `NSString`, but we would need to know what you do with it (it is autoreleased, so you don't need to `release` it, but you could be retaining it somewhere else in your code).

Furthermore, it is not safe to pass `sqlite3_column_text` directly into `stringWithUTF8String`, since in case it returns `nil`, your application will crash.

You might also consider using [fMDB](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/06/new_home_for_fmdb.html), an ObjC wrapper around sqlite3. Find it [here](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).